# Does Variable Declared in Class Extension has Strong Reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I declare a variable on the [class extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3) on the .m file will it all be of Strong reference ? Is it okay to declare like this or not ?

```
    @interface ClassA ()
    {
      UILabel *timeLabel;
      BOOL isNewUI;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ClassA
```

Comment: if you access only in the class A, then it's fine, by default its *Strong*, else if you want to access the more than one class use **@property** for your object

Comment: This is not really an extension and yes, it will be `strong` by default.

Comment: In short: It is Strong reference

Comment: Actually Apple documentation calls it [Class Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're declaring your variables is known as using an iVar, these are strong by default. I wouldn't recommend declaring variables this way as it does not allow you to easily override getters/setters or mark it as readonly.

Instead, I would suggest you declare your variables in the following way:

```
@interface ClassA ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *timeLabel;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isNewUI;

@end

@implementation ClassA

@end
```

This will allow you to choose whether or not your UILabel property is strong or weak. If it's weak and is removed from your view then ARC will take care of removing the reference for you.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped a lot. Actually Apple documentation calls it [Class Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)

Comment: The ivar's are totally fine, and they DO use ARC. They are strong by default, but if you want to make them weak you do: `__weak UILabel *timeLabel;`. Don't have to use `@property` if you don't need to override getters or setters, or not plan to have "readonly".

Comment: It is an extension.

Comment: I stand corrected, I agree that it is an extension. I have amended my answer to reflect that